# Using power automate to read emails received and send out email based on condition

Tags: power-automate

I am trying to use power automate to do my workflow.

Here is my task.

1. Read from an email. This email comes weekly, with the same subject.
2. Read a certain part of the email that has a table. The email contains 3 tables. It is not an attachment but within the body of the email.
3. If the part of the row of table has a certain word, it will grab that whole row and use it as the body of my email to send.
4. It sends an email with and contain that string as the body.

I am getting stuck on part 2-3 as I don't know whcih service to use.

My task is as follows:

- First step: When a new email arrives(V3) ( I set this with the
  subject of the email and the folder it goes to)
- Second step: Get emails (V3) (same subject filter)

What is my next step? This should be where it reads the email and finds that keyword. If it does not see that keyword, the task ends.